# Changing all non-utf8 characters into utf-8 in mysql (encoding problems)

Tags: mysql, regex, encoding, utf-8, notepad++

I have a table in MySQL with several columns and a column called `"abstract"` and I wanted to remove all the non-utf characters exist in `"abstract"` since I need to input them into a text mining program. Abstract contains of lots hexademical value, mathematical symbols, etc.
The problem is I have been trying to convert them using several ways and they all failed:

1. Export data into notepad++, filter out characters using regex (only maintain alphanumeric, special characters) and replace them with space. After that remove `CR LF` in notepad++ using `\r\n` regex. Problem: data get messed up (the lines and delimiter).
2. Export data into notepad++, change encode to ansi, decode to utf-8 without BOM. Problem: it changed to chinese or korean characters, and not changing back to non-utf.
3. Wanted to try the step in mysql by `alter table modify` to `varchar` with `character set latin`, modify again to `blob`, and modify again to `varchar` with `character utf-8`. Problem: my abstract data is so long, and the initial data type is `blob.` I cant change it into other data type because mysql wont accept it and said the data is too long and because it has irrelavant string for varchar data type

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work:

1. Use your approach #1 except removing the CR/LF's.
2. Import data back to database and remove CR/LF's there.